# Array to array join on specific index mongodb

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, join, lookup

I want to get to know about joining to collections array to array based on index of array. Is it possible? If yes, how? What are the semantics, how do we specify array index in join/lookup?

Also,

It would be much appreciated if it could be explained too i.e., how to specify array index while array to string join?

For ref, consider

```
Col A has

Array : [123,124,152,156]

Col B has
Array : [152,245,111,321,657]
```

How can I join if any one or more indexes are same

and

can I join array to string?

```
Col AB
Array : []"aaa","bbb","abc","def"]
Col ABC 
Strings: {"asd","dfg","abc","ettr","def"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work for you [Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-add-objects-into-array-from-another-collection/13988)

Comment: I dont want to concat but to join/lookup based on any one or more same array index. I have updated my question for better understanding